# Thunderbird extension Messaganing Menu and Unity Launcher Integration stopped working

Tags: 11.10, unity-dash, thunderbird, extension, messaging-menu

After I restarted my laptop, the Thunderbird extension stopped working and I can't seem to get it working again.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please define your question. For more details on best practices consider reading the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq#howtoask) on asking questions.Regards

Answer (score 1):

Try the following extensions:

https://launchpad.net/globalmenu-extension

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/messaging-menu-integration/

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/unity-launcher-integration/